# É possível inicializar uma estrutura parcialmente indicando os membros?

Tags: c, c++, struct, declaração-de-variável

Em diversas linguagens é possível inicializar uma `struct`, ou classe, indicando quais membros deseja colocar algum valor:

```
var obj = new Tipo { b = 1, e = "x" };
```

Em C podemos inicializar os membros em ordem:

```
Tipo obj = { 0, 1, 2, 'c', "x" };
```

Mas não funciona se tentar alguns membros pelos seus nomes:

```
Tipo obj = { b = 1, e = "x" };
```

Tem como fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade apenas a sintaxe está errada. Assim funciona:

```
Tipo obj2 = { .b = 1, .e = "x" };
```

O ponto é importante para diferenciar o identificador do membro da estrutura e de uma variável comum.

Essa prática, chamada de **inicializador designado**, pode ser problemática em C já que os outros membros não são inicializados automaticamente. Por isso a técnica é pouco utilizada.

Uma coisa que muita gente não sabe é que dá para fazer a atribuição de estrutura depois de declarada a variável. Isto não funciona:

```
Tipo obj3;
obj3 = { .b = 1, .e = "x" };
```

Mas fazendo um *cast* para indicar para o compilador que o literal é a estrutura que deseja, funciona:

```
Tipo obj3;
obj3 = (Tipo){ .b = 1, .e = "x" };
```

Obviamente funciona com todos os membros sem serem nomeados também.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/QUOcZ6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/otzokbnq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/StructLiteralDeclaration.c).

Comment: E se um dos membros for um ponteiro utiliza-se o `->`?

Comment: Neste caso a inicialização é por valor certo, no caso do ponteiro seria por referencia utilizando a seta `->`, correto?

Comment: @gato na verdade não porque esta é uma sintaxe apenas para desambiguar membro da estrutura e uma variável normal que podem ter o mesmo nome. http://ideone.com/4E3HCn